# MySql One-to-zero to one-to-one

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table Persons with `id` as `pk` and `auto increment`. Then I have a table `Addresses` with `id` as `pk` and `fk` to the `Persons` `id`. But now person can exist without an address, and I don't want a person to exist without an address. I am looking for a standard way to solve this problem. I am using `MySql` and `InnoDB`.

Comment: You do realise that multiple people live at the same address in many cases?

Comment: Yes this is just an example, I am aware this is wrong sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many state changes you want to happen in order for your interaction to be considered a success.

This pretty much defines the "atomic" goal of a transactions.

```
begin; --start the transaction
insert into person values (...);
insert into address values (....);
commit; --finish the transaction
```

This ensures that if there was an error any where along the way all transaction activity is rolled back.  It's an "all or nothing" operation so you don't end up in an in between state you define as undesirable.

Comment: @tony I should have included in my reply that in order for this to be transactional you must use the innodb storage engine.  It is the only mysql engine that supports transactions.